# Comparing two datasets in sas

Tags: sas, compare

I have used proc compare to compare two datasets and have the difference details. But I just want to know whether two datasets are same or not(both content and number of rows wise). Like I have two datasets A and B. Want to just know whether they are same or not. No need of any other difference details. More like I just need to set a flag to 1, if the datasets are different or flag to zero if datasets are same. Is there a way to do it. I searched in internet, all I could see was using proc compare in various ways

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `sysinfo` variable:

```
proc compare noprint base=baseds compare=compareds;
run;

%if %eval(&sysinfo ge 8) %then %do; ...
```

There is a great SAS paper describing the return codes in meticulous detail, available [here](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/063-2012.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Allan Bowe, this is exactly what I needed. I went through the document link that you provided, it was too useful